# ANGULAR JS ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

I am trying to learning angular JS and I am an absolute beginner.I tried using ng-if directives to print 'Mr or Mrs or Ms' according to the their gender and relationship  status.When I bind the married model within the div tag it is giving out the correct value .But the binding after that prints true every time. Are there any other ways to check conditions ?
Moreover I tried checking conditions with the controller , why doesn't that work? Please help!

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myFirstController" ng- init="first='';last='';gender='Male';married='true'">
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="first">
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="last">

    <label for="gender">GENDER </label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" data-ng-model="gender" value="Male" /> MALE
    <input type="radio" name="gender" data-ng-model="gender" value="Female" /> FEMALE
    <br>
    <br>

    <div ng-if="gender==='Female'">
        <input type="radio" name="married" data-ng-model="married" value="true" /> MARRIED
        <input type="radio" name="married" data-ng-model="married" value="false" /> UNMARRIED
        <br>
        <br> {{married}}

    </div>
    <span ng-if="gender==='Male'">MR.</span>
    <span ng-if="gender!=='Male'">
    <span ng-if="married=='true'">MRS.</span>
    <span ng-if="married=='false'">MS.</span> </span>{{first }} {{last}} {{married}}
    <div ng-app="" ng-init="myCol='lightblue'">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `ng-if="gender==='Female'"` by `ng-show="gender==='Female'"`, and it will work fine.

The reason is that `ng-if` creates its own child scope, and the `married` property is thus set on this child scope rather than the controller scope.

The appropriate fix would be to avoid binding directly to properties of the scope, but to bind to properties of an *object* in the scope:

In your controller:

```
$scope.model = {};
```

In your view:

```
<input type="radio" name="married" data-ng-model="model.married" value="true"/>
```

(and same for all your properties, of course).

You should also never use `ng-init`. Just initialize your model from your controller:

```
$scope.model = {
  gender: 'Male',
  married: 'false'
};
```

Finally, a boolean would be a much better choice for the value of `married` that a string containing 'true' or 'false'. You can achieve that using ng-value rather than value:

```
<input type="radio" name="married" data-ng-model="married" ng-value="true"/> 
MARRIED 
<input type="radio" name="married" data-ng-model="married" ng-value="false"/> 
UNMARRIED

<span ng-if="married">MRS.</span>
<span ng-if="!married">MS.</span>
```

[Complete demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/zIiF7d1hsEMLKT6dKzZz?p=preview)

Comment: Yes I have tested it and I can see from your answer why my answer is not correct. Thanks for pointing it out. :) But I will leave my answer as it is since it might be helpful for others in the future

Comment: if($scope.model.married==1)
    {$scope.model.address="MRS.";    }
     else
    {$scope.model.address="MS.";    }

Comment: @GowthamRaj Why do you want to compare a boolean with a number? A boolean is already a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your checks are on strings like `<span ng-if="married=='true'">MRS.</span>` but the `ng-model` for input checkbox binds it to boolean `true` or `false`. So change your code in such a way that wherever there is check with `true` or `false`, it should be boolean value instead of string `'true'` or `'false'`

This

```
<span ng-if="married=='true'">MRS.</span>
<span ng-if="married=='false'">MRS.</span>
```

Should be

```
<span ng-if="married">MRS.</span>
<span ng-if="!married">MRS.</span>
```

Comment: Well, just test it, and you'll see.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me out !